# Detener ciclo for dentro de subclase thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tengo un programa de que al ejecutar el botón <kbd>Start</kbd> en una interfaz gráfica se genera un loop buscando imagen por imagen de una lista.

El problema es que quiero que al presionar el mismo botón (cuyo texto ahora será "Stop") se rompa el ciclo for, he intentado esto con un `threading.Event()` pero no ha dado resultados, de igual forma lo he intentado declarando una variable `detener = False` y luego cambiando la variable a `True` pero resulta igual.

Así quedó el código tras el último intento de resolver este problema sin resultado alguno:

### interfaz.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from imagesearch import *
from ejecutarPrograma import change


raiz = tk.Tk()

startBoton = tk.Button(text="Start",command=lambda widget='startBoton': change(startBoton),height=3,width=20,state="normal")
startBoton.pack(side="bottom")      


raiz.mainloop()
```

### ejecutarPrograma.py

```
from imagesearch import *
import threading
from tkinter import Button
import numpy as np
from time import sleep   


"""
Cambia el boton start en la interfaz grafica a stop y al mismo tiempo comienza el programa
Crea un objeto Detectar = detectar_pantalla
"""

def change(boton):
        Boton = boton
        Detectar = detectar_pantalla()
        if Boton["text"] == "Start":
                print("Detectando pantalla...") 
                Boton.config(text="Stop")
                Detectar.start()
        elif Boton["text"] == "Stop":
                Boton.config(text="Start")
                Detectar.stop()



""" 
busca imágenes dadas en una lista continuamente hasta encontrarse
precision : the higher, the lesser tolerant and fewer false positives are found default is 0.8
retorna una lista con el nombre de la imagen y las coordenadas de su extremo superior izquierdo

    """
    class detectar_pantalla(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self):
                super(detectar_pantalla, self).__init__()
                Thread1 = None
                self.detener = False
                self.pos = None
                self.counter = 0
                self.Image_list = ["images\initiateLink.jpg","images\Suspended_duel.jpg","images\pop_up_ok.jpg",
                "images\Button_next.jpg","images\go_back_button.jpg"]

        def run(self):
                Thread1 = threading.Thread(target = self.search)

        def search(self,timesample=0.5):
                self.counter = 0
                for imagen in self.Image_list:
                        if self.detener:
                                break
                        else:
                                self.pos = imagesearch(imagen)
                                if self.pos[0] == -1:
                                        print(imagen+" not found, waiting")
                                        self.counter += 1
                                        sleep(timesample)
                                        if self.counter == len(self.Image_list):
                                                self.run()
                                elif self.pos[0] != -1:
                                        print(self.pos[0])
                                        if imagen == self.Image_list[0]:
                                                click_image(imagen,self.pos,"left",1)
                                        elif imagen == self.Image_list[2]:
                                                click_image(imagen,self.pos,"left",1)
                                        elif imagen == self.Image_list[4]:
                                                click_image(imagen,self.pos,"left",1)


        def stop(self):
                    self.detener = True


def change(boton):
        Boton = boton
        Detectar = detectar_pantalla()
        if Boton["text"] == "Start":
                print("Detectando pantalla...") 
                Boton.config(text="Stop")
                Detectar.start()
        elif Boton["text"] == "Stop":
                Boton.config(text="Start")
                Detectar.stop()
```

### imagesearch.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import random
import time


 '''
    Searchs for an image on the screen

    input :

    image : path to the image file (see opencv imread for supported types)
    precision : the higher, the lesser tolerant and fewer false positives are found default is 0.8
    im : a PIL image, usefull if you intend to search the same unchanging region for several elements

    returns :
    the top left corner coordinates of the element if found as an array [x,y] or [-1,-1] if not

    '''
    def imagesearch(image, precision=0.8):
        im = pyautogui.screenshot()
        #im.save('testarea.png') usefull for debugging purposes, this will save the captured region as "testarea.png"
        img_rgb = np.array(im)
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        template = cv2.imread(image, 0)
        template.shape[::-1]

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
            if max_val < precision:
                return [-1,-1]
            return max_loc

'''

click on the center of an image with a bit of random.
eg, if an image is 100*100 with an offset of 5 it may click at 52,50 the first time and then 55,53 etc
Usefull to avoid anti-bot monitoring while staying precise.

this function doesn't search for the image, it's only ment for easy clicking on the images.

input :

image : path to the image file (see opencv imread for supported types)
pos : array containing the position of the top left corner of the image [x,y]
action : button of the mouse to activate : "left" "right" "middle", see pyautogui.click documentation for more info
time : time taken for the mouse to move from where it was to the new position
'''

def click_image(image,pos,  action, timestamp,offset=5):
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    pyautogui.moveTo(pos[0] + r(width / 2, offset), pos[1] + r(height / 2,offset),
                     timestamp)
    pyautogui.click(button=action)
```

Comment: Has intentado correr el loop dentro de un `Thread` y hacer que el boton de detener cambie un booleano que rompa el loop?

Comment: @DannyTalent asi?

Comment: Sip, eso se me habia ocurrido. En el `target` no necesitas poner los paréntesis de la función (sería `target = self.search` solamente). Te ayudó? Otra cosa, no lo pongas como respuesta a menos que te haya servido! Sino edita la pregunta original

Comment: @DannyTalent Ok ya edité el código disculpa, la verdad cuando coloco el target sin el paréntesis por alguna razón la función "search" no se ejecuta y si lo coloco con el paréntesis se ejecuta pero sigue el mismo error (el loop no cierra)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema principal es que **cada vez que se llama a la función `change` (pulsas el botón) creas un nuevo hilo sin detener al anterior si existe y está en ejecución**, usando el método `start` o `stop` indistintamente  sobre ese nuevo hilo siempre, en vez de llamar al método `stop` del hilo en ejecución:

```
def change(boton):
    Boton = boton
    Detectar = detectar_pantalla()  # <<<<<<< Nuevo hilo
    if Boton["text"] == "Start":
        Detectar.start()
    elif Boton["text"] == "Stop":
        Detectar.stop()    # <<<<<<< Método stop del nuevo hilo
```

lo que debes hacer es mantener una referencia al hilo que tienes en ejecución y usar dicha referencia para detener el hilo.

Además de eso, otras observaciones:

- Hay un problema importante con esto:

  ```
   if self.counter == len(self.Image_list):
       self.run()
  ```

  Aparte que **el método `run` solo debe llamarse una vez**, esto crea una **llamada recursiva potencialmente sin fin**. Python limita el numero de llamadas recursivas para proteger la pila, por lo que aún sin tener en cuenta lo de la llamada única, esto causaría que tu hilo eventualmente terminara abruptamente con una excepción.

  Por ejemplo, es mucho más simple y eficiente si usas un ciclo `while` infinito con el `for` anidado dentro para conseguir que se itere repetidamente sobre la lista.
- Te aconsejo no mover la callback del botón a otro módulo, no hay una razón para separarla del módulo que implementa la interfaz y hacerlo deja el código menos claro y dificulta sin necesidad alguna la tarea. De hecho, si usas una clase para implementar tu GUI, con la callback del botón como un método de instancia, puedes usar un atributo de clase para la referencia al hilo, simplificandolo todo bastante.
- Es recomendable que sigas las [convenciones de estilo para código Python definidas en PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) para hacer tu código más legible. No uses mayúsculas en nombres de funciones, métodos o módulos. Las mayúsculas se reservan para las clases, que se nombran usando CamelCase. Las funciones, métodos y módulos se nombran en minúscula separando las palabras con `_`.
- Las cadenas de documentación para funciones/métodos/clases no van antes de la definición, van en la primera linea dentro de ella. Tal como lo tienes ahora, son solo cadenas, no van a poder ser usadas como docstrings por los IDEs, `help()` o cualquier parser de documentación:

  - [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar triple comillas dobles (""") y almohadilla (#) para comentar en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/281455/15089)
- Es altamente recomendable que tu hilo se defina como demonio, en caso contrario, si cierras la aplicación o ésta termina inesperadamente con un hilo hijo en ejecución, el hilo seguirá ejecutándose infinitamente.
- No uses `\` en cadenas que representen rutas, `\` se usa para definir secuencias de escape como `"\s"` (espacio), `"\n"` (nueva linea), `"\r"` (retorno de carro), `"\U"` (carácter unicode), `"\t"` (tabulación), etc. Esto causaque termines con rutas inválidas o incorrectas, por ejemplo `"foo\script"` termina siendo en realidad `"foo cript"`... Puedes escapar la barra (`"mi\\ruta"`) o usar cadenas crudas (`r"mi\ruta"`), pero en ciertos casos son también mala idea. Te recomiendo usar siempre `/` para las rutas, que además es universal entre sistemas.

Un ejemplo de como podría quedar el código:

### interfaz.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from imgdeteccion import DetectarPantalla


class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.start_button = tk.Button(
            text="Start",
            command=self.start_search,
            height=3,
            width=20,
            state="normal"
            )
        self.start_button.pack(side="bottom")
        self._thread = None

    def start_search(self):
        if self._thread is None:
            self._thread = DetectarPantalla()
            self._thread.start()
            self.start_button["text"] = "Stop"
        else:
            self._thread.stop()
            self.start_button["text"] = "Start"
            self._thread = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raiz = tk.Tk()
    MainApp(raiz).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    raiz.mainloop()
```

### imgdeteccion.py

```
from time import sleep
import threading
from imagesearch import click_image, imagesearch


class DetectarPantalla(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.detener = threading.Event()
                self.daemon = True
                self.pos = None
                self.image_list = [
                    "images/initiateLink.jpg", "images/Suspended_duel.jpg",
                    "images/pop_up_ok.jpg", "images/Button_next.jpg",
                    "images/go_back_button.jpg"
                    ]
                self.timesample = 0.5

        def run(self):
            while True:
                for index, imagen in enumerate(self.image_list):
                    if self.detener.is_set():
                        return

                    self.pos = imagesearch(imagen)
                    if self.pos[0] == -1:
                        print(imagen + " not found, waiting")
                        sleep(self.timesample)

                    else:
                        print(self.pos[0])
                        if index == 0:
                            click_image(imagen, self.pos, "left", 1)
                        elif index == 2:
                            click_image(imagen, self.pos, "left", 1)
                        elif index == 4:
                            click_image(imagen, self.pos, "left", 1)

        def stop(self):
            self.detener.set()
```

No he tocado `imagesearch.py`. Las cadenas de documentación las he suprimido pero solo por hacer el código menos extenso, siempre es buena idea que tu código las tenga.

Comment: Genial! leeré todo lo que recomiendas antes de seguir adelante con el programa. Te agradezco mucho la ayuda!

Comment: @Gregori Recuerda aceptar la respuesta de FJSevilla si resolvió tu problema o duda.

Comment: @JulioCesar muy bien! aprecio mucho todo consejo e información ya que soy nuevo en la plataforma

Comment: Okay, Saludos!!

Comment: ¿has probado a usar las variables de tkinter?
detener =  Boolvar(False)
y luego detener.set(True)